NWConnection works on local machine but fails on build server
I'm using NWConnection to communicate between two local processes, which is working on a local machine, but when running tests on our build machines (run by TeamCity) the connection is getting interrupted somehow.
I connect like so:
    let parameters = NWParameters.tcp
    parameters.requiredInterfaceType = .loopback
    guard let port = NWEndpoint.Port(rawValue: portNumber)
    else { throw Error.portInvalid }
    let connection = NWConnection(host: "localhost", port: port, using: parameters)

and eventually send some data:
    connection.send(content: data,
                    contentContext: .finalMessage,
                    completion: .contentProcessed(···))

I can do this successfully on my local machine using contentContext: .finalMessage. If I use the recommended .defaultMessage then the message doesn't seem to actually get sent until the connection is closed, but I need it open still so the other app can send a response.
On a build machine however, immediately after the call to NWConnetion.send(), this appears next in the logs:

(Network) [com.apple.network:connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5.1.1:1] Socket received WRITE_CLOSE event

The other app still receives the message, but it can't send the response because the connection is closed.
What could cause the connection to spontaneously close on some computers but not others? Is there some different way of configuring the connection to avoid the problem?
